# Using a data structure to take a value given by the user to put into an array to later be printed out

Tags: c

What I'm trying to do is make a program that asks the user a name and a phone number. I want to take that information and put it into a data structure so that I can later put the information in the structure in alphabetical order. Where I'm running in trouble is putting the string into the array in the data structure. Apologize for this being a basic level question, just learning about C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static char name, number;

typedef struct phoneBook {
    char personName[10];
    char phoneNumber[10];
} book;

void processBook(book *);

main()
{
    book person = {0};
    book *ptrBook;

    ptrBook = &person;

    processBook(ptrBook);
    printf("What is the name: ");
    scanf("%s",&name);
    printf("What is the number: ");
    scanf("%s",&number);
    printf("\nName: %s\n", ptrBook -> personName);
    printf("Phone Number: %s\n", ptrBook -> phoneNumber);
}

void processBook(book *e)
{
    strcpy(e -> personName, &name);
    strcpy(e -> phoneNumber, &number);
}
```

Comment: What are the global variables `name` and `number`? How many characters does each of the variables fit? And why are they global? And you don't even need them at all, just scan directly into `person.name` and `person.phoneNumber`.

Comment: Also, you're trying to copy the name and the number *before* reading them from the user.

Comment: I was trying to make them a place holder from the scanf(); function that I would make a pointer to assign to the char personName[10]. Do I have to make them arrays?

Comment: @stevejohn you declared them as `char`, while you probably meant `char *` (and subsequent memory allocation) or `char[10]`

Comment: Ahh thank you @FedericoklezCulloca so just to check should I write it as static char *name, *number or are you saying char *personName?

Comment: The first, but you also need to allocate space for them with `malloc`. Or ditch them altogether like @Someprogrammerdude says.

Comment: Thank you guys so much just got it to read. You all have been great.